# How can I display RTSP stream on a webpage in 2021 (very low load)?

Tags: javascript, html, rtsp

I want to make an open-source project involving displaying an RTSP stream on a webpage with React. I need to be able to specify RTSP URL in my frontend code. VLC plugin doesn't seem to work in all browsers, and a few other solutions I found are relatively expensive. My project won't be opened much, only by people who want to check out my work, so I won't cause high load and I need something free or with a price corresponding my usage of the system.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: ffmpeg  can help you.  It can streams using rtsp protocol.  it's opensource and free.

Comment: Thanks! It appears I'm going to need a server to convert the stream first. Not exactly a frontend-only solution, but I'll look into it.